# Getting connection refused error on authentication ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I am following this tutorial to make google authentication with Angular and ASP.NET Core:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-sign-in-with-google-in-angular-and-use-jwt-based-net-core-api-authentication-rsa-6635719fb86c

But I'm getting a "connection refused" error in the ASP.NET Core side.

Here is my Angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SocialAuthService  } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  user: SocialUser | null;
  hasApiAccess = false;

  constructor(private authService: SocialAuthService, private http: HttpClient)
  {
    this.user = null;
    this.authService.authState.subscribe((user: SocialUser) => {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:5001/user/authenticate', { idToken: user.idToken }).subscribe((authToken: any) => {
          console.log(authToken);

          let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authToken.authToken
          });
          this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:5002/secured', { headers: reqHeader }).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.hasApiAccess = true;
          })
        })
      }
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  signInWithGoogle(): void {
    this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then((x: any) => console.log(x));
  }


  signOut(): void {
    this.authService.signOut();
    this.hasApiAccess = false;
  }
}
```

The controller is as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace GoogleAuthRest.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SecuredController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Test()
        {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

And the startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
    
namespace GoogleAuthRest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        //configure barer token
        public class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
        {
            public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
            {
                RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
                rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(PUBLIC_KEY), out _);

                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "AuthService",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = "GoogleAuthRest",
                    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory()
                    {
                        CacheSignatureProviders = false
                    }
                };
            }

            public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
        //end

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // configure Angular client
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularDevClient",
                  builder =>
                  {
                      builder
                      .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod();
                  });
            });
            //end

            // Add authentication tokens
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer();
            //end

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "GoogleAuthRest", Version = "v1" });
            });

            // This is the tricky part to inject the configuration so the public key is used to validate the JWT
            services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "GoogleAuthRest v1"));
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAngularDevClient");
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }

        private const string PUBLIC_KEY = @"MIICCgKCAgEAtCR2Pii+q9C76P2E9ydHYxnBPjJFGT7MvHuQPKpcS9RImfrkobt0
        LPS/406eWm/tRBvnYD9nDpHJNKN3TjEenFQuDGR4RHcGK/e43SAhTAi7+s0tfAQd
        6BK4gznIwvs5cWyilh1B7c9sCnxhJ/EYLIe1N2yiD8mhvfojIF4vMYxONIMTGYXy
        87lnO9zRAdXAZ39YbtmFmQwK8gfXX5d/XVlKy0tc2y5bRY5iXn9kwqwvFlzL6O4v
        pjhqA5kwsJV7efhL9nU0ACR4dG3zwFR3SAOOSETXjnfmjH2ocga+oa65ToypUz2L
        1DwnNHt+M5CtDJ9um4dbYaqfBWkjWe3FuGB0GNPS8pbX2nVt76OfHA/QKmxTWvFd
        POZnjpg2QhDujyXgoIY731zx5bAklKVoKFma/qfWfCyCSTUzhgu1KQm9swipMsQy
        NYr9CjbnIlPn4EvrBIbGcIiaRNCLCIlcAuxE/GiH1zBUfeJxfJQmurejp6mBAtAS
        FY08DmUebBz8mlUbB+LXMYKHZ4GK6TecPy0WJU2qRMQ//PKfOa+wkesp4M53SQdp
        ItDp5akTzYUo4rXwk3HPCtemKaSNhyG+EYtZ1CAmPN5sEjU0/x0Dq7SU5o8KhogB
        m/5HRJ3M9dMRcwD3OcsMl0kW1PPUt04itboS3SlFav90V9uc2YNGpPsCAwEAAQ==";
    }
}
```

May be someone has read this article and is able to help me with that...

I also tried to comment out `validateAudience`. This did not help

Comment: Hello was the given soltuion resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your cors policy was not created the right way.

Use:-

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularDevClient", builder => builder
                .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod())
        );
```

instead of:-

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAngularDevClient",
                  builder =>
                  {
                      builder
                      .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      .AllowAnyMethod();
                  });
            });
```

Or you can normally use:-

```
 services.AddCors();
```

then your configure service:-

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("https://localhost:4200"));
```

hope it will resolve your issue.